# How to pass argument for FactoryGirl method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

There is the following code for creating objects:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    name    'Some name'
    phone   '89277777777'
    address 'Some address'
  end

  factory :order do
    title   'Some title'
  end
end
```

User model has got `has_many :orders` association, and is it possible to pass `user` factory to `order` factory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    name    'Some name'
    phone   '89277777777'
    address 'Some address'
  end

  factory :order do
    user
    title   'Some title'
  end
end
```

In your specs:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:order)
```

will create both an order object and an associated user object.

more information on FactoryGirl with Rails - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution is as simple as using the association method

```
factory :order do
  title   'Some title'
  association :user
end
```

that can be shortened to

```
factory :order do
  title   'Some title'
  user
end
```

A word of warning. This approach tends to make your application very slow as long as the complexity of your models will increase.

In fact, if you have a purchase associated to an order associated to an user, etc, then creating a Purchase will create on cascade all the associated records even if you don't need them. Your tests will become slower over the time.

I suggest you to [use the traits to compose your associations](http://pivotallabs.com/how-to-use-factorygirl-effectively/) only when required.

```
factory :order do
  title   'Some title'

  trait :with_user do
    user
  end
end

FactoryGirl.create(:order, :with_user)
```

I normally also use `:with_fake_user` when I need the user id to be present for validation, but I'm testing something that doesn't require to access the user.

```
factory :order do
  title   'Some title'

  trait :with_user do
    user
  end
  trait :with_fake_user do
    user_id 0
  end
end

FactoryGirl.create(:order, :with_user)
FactoryGirl.create(:order, :with_fake_user)
```